# Why is Eclipse asking me to throw an exception?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an app that uses class Employee. So far, I created the class, three objects, and all other necessary stuff. I want to read a web file, so I created EditText object for user input (where he/she will input the url address of the file). I need to use the web file in order for my class objects to use the methods (say, getMethod()) to get the data. Eclipse is asking me to create the try/catch statement for the URL object. I don't want to let Eclipse do that, but I want to do it manually. How would I do that? Here is my code, assuming everything else is correct (references, EditText, TextView, variable, permission in the manifest, etc):

```
//Store the URL address when user input it and assign the data
    //to variable (reference) urlfile 
    urlfile = edt1.getText().toString();

    //Create an URL object that read urlfile
    URL file_url = new URL(urlfile);
    try
    {
        //try to open the file from the web
        Scanner fsc = new Scanner(file_url.openStream());

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        tv.setText("Error: Invalid URL Address or File Does Not Exist");
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. Your code already contains one try-catch that you can refer to and learn from it. It would have been faster for you to just try it out than post a question.

Comment: I am confused on which part you want to do manually.

Comment: *Eclipse is asking me to create the try/catch statement for the URL object. I don't want to let Eclipse do that, but I want to do it manually.* Then what's your exact problem?

Comment: The part that puzzled me is the line of code that states  URL file_url = new URL(urlfile); That is where Eclipse is asking me to either throw declaration or use try/catch.

Comment: My advice, ditch Eclipse. Stick with your command line and a text editor for now.

Comment: @SovMoose that's a bad advice. Creating a new instance of `URL` can throw an exception and the IDE is notifying you about it. Trying to ignore it by using a text editor **is a bad idea** and will end in compilation errors. Please don't give such bad advices in the future.

Comment: @Luiggi sure it will result in compilation errors. That's precisely the idea. In no way I am saying that it should be ignored by using a text editor. From what I understood is that OP does not have a strong grasp on the necessity of catching exceptions and did not understand why eclipse was forcing such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The java.net.URL constructor declares MalformedURLException as a possible exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String%29).  Therefore you need to either catch it or declare that your method throws it.
I don't know why you don't want eclipse to correct it (the quick fixes in eclipse can be very helpful and improve your productivity).

In any case, because `MalformedURLException` extends `IOException` so moving your `URL` constructor call into the try-catch you already have, will remove the compile time error.